# Rxjs for polling causing multiple repeating api calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

Polling here means- making api call regularly in intervals after given time ie refreshInterval and updating data.

I am trying to apply polling(ie- api call based on some `refreshInterval`)  but its repeating api calls and also making 1000 api calls continuously and response is also not coming.

Multiple calls are going continuously irrespective of polling time. Its subscribing each second for every api call irrespective of polling time provided.

Whats the bug here or whats the correct way to do this?

## .ts

```
ngOnInit(){
// loop for demonstration
 for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
   makeApiCall(refreshInterval, url, params, payload) //<=== looping based on some json
 }

}

public makeApiCall(refreshInterval, url, params, payload){
interval(refreshInterval * 1000)
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        flatMap(() => this.serviceInvoker.invoke(url, params, payload)),
      ).subscribe(
        (success) => {
        },
        (err) => {

   }
  )
}
```

Comment: Is the `refreshInterval` supposed to be dynamic for each call?

Comment: yes, the refresh interval are different based on loop as per json

Comment: Could you clarify which JSON? I don't see any object in your code at the moment. You are passing a constant `refreshInterval` for each iteration in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
public makeApiCall(refreshInterval, url, params, payload) {
    interval(refreshInterval * 1000)
//...
```

The first call of `makeApiCall` is with the value of `refreshInterval` being 0. Here's a stackblitz of what happens when you try do to something with interval 0:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rrnu4d?file=index.ts

You need `timer`, not `interval`. And better yet, do something like

```
interval(1000).pipe(
    take(5),
    flatMap(() => this.serviceInvoker.invoke( //...
```

Comment: Can you please, help me how to use timer here.

Comment: This does not help as I am calling this interval method on for loop and in each iteration passing different refereshInterval(polling) time. Multiple calls are still going  continuously irrespective of polling time. Its subscribing each second for every api call  irrespective of polling time provided.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP call is asynchronous. So you might be making invoking another HTTP call while the previous one has not completed yet. Each browser has certain threshold for simultaneous connections per host (eg. Chrome - 6) above which all the HTTP requests would be put on hold till the previous requests return a response. That is why you don't get any response.

You also say you need to repeat the call **after** updating the data. At the moment you are repeating the call without the knowledge of whether the request has been completed or not.

For that, you could use `setTimeout()` inside each callback for a workaround instead of the loop. But beware it comes with heavy caveats. Once called, the function is repeated continuously unless it is stopped by `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`.

```
private timeoutId: any;

public makeApiCall(refreshInterval, url, params, payload) {
  this.serviceInvoker.invoke(url, params, payload).subscribe(
    (success) => {
      // handle success
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { this.makeApiCall(url, params, payload) }, refreshInterval * 1000);
    },
    (err) => { 
      // handle error 
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { this.makeApiCall(url, params, payload) }, refreshInterval * 1000);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: I am trying it in Rxjs way using timer or interval or delay or repeat etc

Comment: You could pipe a delay and repeat to achieve the effect in Rxjs. But you might run into multiple simultaneous API calls again, because you do not if the previous request has been finished or not. The only way to know correctly is to check inside the callback, which I am doing now in my answer.

Comment: Also you could repeat the call for different intervals. For eg., different time intervals based on if you received a response or an error.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/recipes/http-polling           Example 2: Simple http polling . It is what I want to achieve but not helpful in for loop. Although your codes might help but its dependent on window.setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pretty similar use case

```
from(fakeDelayedRequest()).pipe(
  map((response) => {
    if (isValidResponse(response)) {
      return response;
    } else {
      throw `Not a valid response`;
    }
  }),
  retry({
    // getRetryDelayTimeOrThrow decides if we retry or not, depending on the error
    //  - returns an observable that triggers when the next request shall be sent
    //  - or throws the error which leads to exiting the retry loop
    delay: getRetryDelayTimeOrThrow,
  }),
  timeout({
    each: maxTimeout,
    with: () => throwError(() => 'TIMEOUT'),
  })
);

function getRetryDelayTimeOrThrow(e: any, retryCount: number) {
  console.error(e);

  if (repeatAfterError(e)) {
    return timer(getPollInterval(retryCount));
  } else {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

You can find the full working code [in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-http-polling-qmjsxa?devtoolsheight=80&file=index.ts)